# Impoving performance of query by using greater than on a primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a Reporting table where i store description

```
tableA

sno   | Project |name     | description      | mins |
1     | prjA    |nameA    |ABC -10% task done|  30  |
...
3000  | prjA    |nameB    |ABC -70% task done|  70  |
```

i want to query the description field and save in another table

```
tableB

id | valueStr | total_mins  | last_sno
1  |  ABC     | 100         | 3000
```

if there is no entry in second table , i create a entry with default values

if there is and entry in second table , i update 2nd table , with the `total_mins` and increment the `last_sno` to that value say 3300 , so that the next time i query this table i get values from second table and based on the `last_sno`

```
Query

SELCT last_sno FROM tableB where valueStr ='ABC'
```

the first 3 characters in the description field

```
SELECT max(sno), sum(mins) FROM tableA
 where sno > last_sno and description like 'ABC%'
```

Since the first table has million of rows so, i search the first table with `sno > last_sno` , so that should help performance right ?

but the explain shows that it scans the same no of rows , when i query the first table from the first `sno`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `valueStr` has a Unique constraint on the second table, so the following query will always yield at most one row:

```
SELECT last_sno 
FROM tableB 
WHERE valueStr ='ABC'
```

You can use it as a subquery (or a derived table) to run an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO tableB 
  (valueStr, total_mins, last_sno)
SELECT 
  'ABC', SUM(a.mins), MAX(a.sno)
FROM tableA AS a
WHERE a.sno > COALESCE(
          ( SELECT last_sno 
            FROM tableB 
            WHERE valueStr ='ABC'
          ), 0) 
  AND a.description LIKE 'ABC%'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  total_mins = total_mins + VALUES(total_mins),
  last_sno = VALUES(last_sno) ;
```

---

Regarding efficiency, the condition you have

```
WHERE a.sno > @last_sno
  AND a.description LIKE 'ABC%'
```

is basically two range conditions, one on `sno` and one on `description` (think of `description LIKE 'ABC%'` the same as `description >= 'ABC' AND description < 'ABD'`) which is rather hard to optimize. The optimizer will have to choose one index to use, it can't use both indexes for this query.

If you could split the `description` column or add one more with the first (three or more) characters of `description` that uniquely identify the `value_str`, making `tableA` something like this:

```
tableA

sno   | Project |name     | description      | value_str | mins |
1     | prjA    |nameA    |ABC -10% task done| ABC       | 30   |
...
3000  | prjA    |nameB    |ABC -70% task done| ABC       | 70   |
```

then you could write the conditions as:

```
WHERE a.sno > @last_sno
  AND a.value_str = 'ABC'
```

and a composite index on `(value_str, sno)` would make this and similar queries much more efficient than what you have now.